# Rを使ったローリング回帰がうまくワークしません。（PerformanceAnalyticsno）

Tags: r

以下のコードでローリング回帰を行いたいのですが、
↓のようなエラーがでしまいます。。。。対応方法を教えて頂きたいです。

```
coefs= rollapplyr(dataset1, size.window, function(x){
+   coef(lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=x))}, by.column = FALSE)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = x,  : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array
```

```r
#packageのインストールはRstudioの Tools>Install packages から実行

library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)

#所定のフォルダ内のCSVファイルを取得
setwd("パス名")
x =read.csv("ファイル名.csv")

dataset = data.frame(x)

y = dataset[,"A"]
x1 = dataset[,"B"]
x2 = dataset[,"C"]
x3 = dataset[,"D"]
x4 = dataset[,"E"]

#ほしいデータのみのDataframeを再構築
dataset1 = data.frame(A = y,B = x1, C =x2, D = x3, E = x4)

#↓のコードを実行したところエラーが発生。dataset1は正しく組成できていることは確認済
size.window = 120
coefs= rollapplyr(dataset1, size.window, function(x){
  coef(lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=x))}, by.column = FALSE)
```

Comment: `rollapplyr` は function に matrix を渡すので、`data=as.data.frame(x)` とすると良いかも知れません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ちなみに上のコードにおいて、function(x)にで渡している変数xはdataset1にあたるという認識なのですが正しいでしょうか？
その場合、dataset1 = data.frame(A = y,B = x1, C =x2, D = x3, E = x4)
でdata.frameとして構築しているのですが、これではワークしないのでしょうか？？

Comment: ここでは `by.column = FALSE` と指定されていますので、function(x)で渡している変数xはdataset1の行(row)になります(一行ごとにfunctionの内容が適用されます）。

Comment: ありがとうございます。以下のようい再度data.frameで型を指定してみましたが、やはりうまくいきませんでした。。。

dataset1 = data.frame(Y = y,X1 = x1, X2 =x2)
dataset2 = as.data.frame(dataset1)

size.window = 120
coefs= rollapplyr(dataset2, size.window, function(x){
  coef(lm(Y~X1+X2,data=x))}, by.column = FALSE)

Comment: どうやらdataframeではなくmatrixに変換する必要があるみたいです。matrixに変換したところコードが動きました。